# What items can companions interact with?

Tags: fallout-4

I am looking for specific aid, clothes, junk items, or special "costumes" with which companions can interact when you're in build mode or when waiting.

For example:

#### Costumes

- Codsworth can wear a bowler hat.
- Dogmeat can wear wraparound goggles.

#### Junk/environment

Dogmeat, when waiting, will play with a teddy bear if he has one in his inventory, and if the dog house is presented, he will rest there.

#### Aid

Cait, while waiting, can be seen taking chems if she has them in inventory (same with Nuka-Cola, but I haven't tested it yet).

There must be much more stuff like this, and I didn't spend the time needed with every companion to dig deep enough and uncover these details. So what else do you encounter in the game?

Comment: Regarding the dog house, I believe that was one of the most common causes for "where did Dogmeat go" when you have him wait in Sanctuary, where there are multiple dog houses, some which are in secluded spots.

Answer (score 1):

They can use pretty much all chairs and beds. As well as other outpost-specific furniture like desks.

Also if assigned to a certain outpost, companions and other NPCs belonging to the outpost may patrol, guard, cook, do farmer duties, use water pumps etc. They will also use workbenches.

You can also assign companions belonging to an outpost to run caravans (not Dogmeat obviously, but both the robots can do so). Quite handy if you have an ambush problem in some risky caravan route - let Danse or someone in power armor handle it. (Most ambushes only trigger when the player is near anyway.)

Oh, and all humanoid characters love to wear/steal available power armor in case the outpost gets attacked.